# How to throw compilation error from an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

there are [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664620%28VS.71%29.aspx) in .NET (e.g. [`ObsoleteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664623%28VS.71%29.aspx)) which are able to prevent compilation or at least throw compile time warnings depending on their configuration.

How to write an attribute that is able to interfere with compilation? Is there a way to do this from outside Microsoft?

Comment: Unfortunately, the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664620%28VS.71%29.aspx has gone stale.

Comment: There is some useful information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/general

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Obsolete` attribute is "compiler magic" - you can't do something like this on your own without modifying the compiler. However, as always, there are workarounds - e.g. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150/create-an-attribute-to-break-the-build) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings/154254) thread.

Comment: These are links to answers, not really an answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Any attributes that exhibit this inside the compiler are special cases. The `[Obsolete]` behaviour is described in the C# spec (17.4.3), for example.

You could [write a custom FxCop rule](http://www.guysmithferrier.com/downloads/FxCop.pdf)?

Comment: That doesn't give you the opportunity to give you a compile time error/warning, does it ?

Comment: It does if you include FxCop in your build process. In VS2008 (team developer edition) you can do this either by declaring a build symbol, or clicking a checkbox on project properties...

Comment: For info, it is the CODE_ANALYSIS symbol, or the checkbox on the "Code Analysis" tab.