# Attribute that gives compiler warning C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, attributes, compiler-warnings

I am trying to create an attribute that mimics the behavior of the ObsoleteAttribute, in the sense that it gives a compiler warning, but I would like to have a different warning string, different attribute name, and maintain the green underline if the property is used in visual studio.

I have tried overriding the ObsoleteAttribute, but it is sealed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425806/4034168

Comment: Guess its sealed for good reason. Just use [Obsolete]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to throw compilation error from an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425806/how-to-throw-compilation-error-from-an-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very stale question.  It seems to me that you could ship your special attribute with a Roslyn analyzer.  Your analyzer could examine syntax elements that have your special attribute and provide errors/warnings, and etc.

This may be more work that just inheriting from OnbsoleteAttribute, but it is doable, and rather flexible.