# How to mark a code section with a warning purposely in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pragma

is it possible to for example use #pragma to raise a custom warning within the VS IDE? I'd need it for a while because there are two classes in this code that contain the very same data but derive from very different classes (Attribute, EventArgs). So if one modified the former class without modifying the latter, the whole system would stop working.

As long as there is no solution, I'd like to raise this custom warning so that everybody trying to start a new build must agree on that they recognized the code smell.

Comment: This sounds like a case for code generation, an interface or shared class

Comment: I'm agreeing with Daniel. This seems like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to throw compilation error from an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425806/how-to-throw-compilation-error-from-an-attribute)

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't like interfaces, because they cause more trouble than relief. Plus they trigger yet more copy & paste.

Comment: Your question sounds like a required copy paste

Comment: @CarstenP, no, interfaces don't trigger more copy & paste

Comment: @CarstenP As Gian Paolo said, `#warning` should help your needs. If it solves your problem, you should mark it as answer, it will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking [#warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#error-and-warning-information) directive

```
#warning careful with this method, if modified you have to modify this and that.
```

Comment: Thanks tons, and @admins: closable =)